# Using LoadImage for resources win32

Tags: visual-c++, wic

I have a program that Im using OpenFileName and GetOpenFileName to get a file and using Windows Imaging Component to convert it to a DIBSection then using BitBlt to draw it to the window.

I want to do the same with my resource files so I use LoadImage, but when I try to convert it using Windows Imaging Component I get an access violation and it says error reading characters of string.

This is how I use LoadImage

```
LoadImage(NULL,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BACKGROUND),0,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

Whats my problem here?

Comment: See [How to load a bitmap from a resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756685(v=vs.85).aspx), which is part of a Direct2D sample application.

Answer (score 4):

DO not use LR_LOADFROMFILE as the last parameter. When this parameter is used, the function loads from a file. Pass NULL, or LR_SHARED (if you are planning to use it somewhere else in the program)

Comment: I changed the last argument to null but I still get the error from the second argument.